# Message truncated to 16k sending from TCPSocket to EventMachine

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have a client ruby process that is attempting to send data to a service built on EventMachine.  The workflow is simple. The client always initiates a request and always expects a response in return.

When sending data from the TCPSocket it apparently is truncating the data to roughly 16k. Any recommendations on what I'm doing wrong or what assumptions I've made that I need to rethink? Presumably I'm doing something wrong in EM where I need to accumulate all the data that's being sent but I'm not sure how.

```
# client.rb
def send_messages arr
  arr = Array(messages)
  if arr.length > 0
    logger.debug { "Sending #{ arr.length } messages" }


    marshaled = Marshal.dump(arr)
    logger.debug { "Marshaled data #{ marshaled.length } bytes" } # roughly 200k

    socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
    written = socket.write(marshaled)
    logger.debug { "Apparently sent #{ written } bytes" } # same size
    socket.close_write

    data = socket.read
    logger.debug { "Received #{ data.length } bytes from service" }
    Marshal.load(data)
  end

rescue Exception => ex
  logger.error "Client threw exception communicating with service :: #{ ex.message }"
  raise ex
ensure
  socket.close if socket
end
```

The logging on the client side looks like:

```
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.908857 #9360] DEBUG -- : Sending 1 messages 
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.909907 #9360] DEBUG -- : Marshaled data length 205941 bytes
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.910373 #9360] DEBUG -- : Apparently sent 205941 bytes
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.955270 #9360] DEBUG -- : Received 0 bytes from service
```

On the server side...

```
class EventedServer < EM::Connection

  attr_reader :context

  def initialize context
    raise "Context must be defined" unless context
    @context = context
  end

  def post_init
    logger.debug { "-- someone connected to the server" }
  end

  def connection_completed
    logger.debug { "-- connection completed" }
  end

  def unbind
    logger.debug { "-- unbind" }
  end

  def receive_data data
    logger.debug { "-- received data at the server #{ data.length }" } # approx 16k
    send_data(process(data))
  end

  def process request

    logger.debug { "-- about to deserialize #{ request.length } bytes" }
    model = Marshal.load(request)
    logger.debug { "-- received #{ model.class.name }" }

    context.process_message(model)

    # Send data the application needs to stay up to date.
    response = context.application(app_name).pending_configurations
    logger.debug { "-- about to send #{ response.keys } for #{ app_name }" }
    Marshal.dump(response)
  rescue Exception => e
    logger.error("** Error in processing request of #{ request.length } bytes")
    raise e
  end
end
```

The logging on the server side looks like:

```
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.910251 #9330] DEBUG -- : In evented server initialize...
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.910319 #9330] DEBUG -- : -- someone connected to the server
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.910419 #9330] DEBUG -- : -- received data at the server 16384
D, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.910463 #9330] DEBUG -- : -- about to deserialize 16384 bytes
E, [2017-01-12T10:02:56.912067 #9330] ERROR -- : ** Error in processing request of 16384 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is `receive_data` does not wait to return all data like I thought it did. A buffer is required. In my case, any message greater than 16k needs to be buffered. My current code looks something like this:

```
  def post_init
    logger.debug { "-- someone connected to the server" }
    @buffer = []
    logger.debug { "-- initializing message buffer" }
  end

  DELIMITER = "\nDELIM\n"

  def receive_data data

    # NOTE: actual code checks to ensure data was not split in the delimiter
    if data.ends_with?(DELIMITER)
      logger.debug { "-- received data at the server #{ data.length }" }
      @buffer << data[0...(-1*DELIMITER.length)]
      joined_data = @buffer.join
      @buffer = []

      logger.debug { "-- total data received #{ joined_data.length }" }
      send_data(process(joined_data))
    else
      logger.debug { "-- received partial data at the server #{ data.length }" }
      @buffer << data
    end
  end
```